# Ambiguous type of Avro record generated with Python

Tags: python, avro

I'm using Python Avro implementation. I declared field **person** with 3 possible instances - null, Man and Woman:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"Example",
    "namespace":"marboni",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"person",
            "type":[
                "null",
                {
                    "type":"record",
                    "name":"Man",
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "name":"gym",
                            "type": "string",
                            "default":null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type":"record",
                    "name":"Woman",
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "name":"beautySalon",
                            "type": "string",
                            "default":null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I write record assuming that it's a Man:

```
writer = DataFileWriter(open('result.avro', 'w'), DatumWriter(), SCHEMA)
writer.append({
    'person': {
        'gym': 'Sport 4 Live'
    }
})
writer.close()


reader = DataFileReader(open('result.avro', 'r'), DatumReader())
for row in reader:
    print row
reader.close()
```

Result is predictable:

```
{u'person': {u'gym': u'Sport 4 Live'}}
```

Then I add NULL to the Man's "gym" field and Woman's "beautySalon" fields:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"Example",
    "namespace":"marboni",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"person",
            "type":[
                "null",
                {
                    "type":"record",
                    "name":"Man",
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "name":"gym",
                            "type": ["null", "string"],
                            "default":null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type":"record",
                    "name":"Woman",
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "name":"beautySalon",
                            "type": ["null", "string"],
                            "default":null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Running the same code and getting:

```
{u'person': {u'beautySalon': None}}
```

Oops, with nullable fields our man became woman. Sad.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: I would think that avro differentiates between the different union options based on type. I would suggest adding a sex field to record, but you could also create a man_record and woman_record

Comment: What do you mean by creating man_record and woman_record? And how sex field helps us?